# Simple C++ CLR stopwatch

Tags: visual-c++, clr, stopwatch

For a project, I need to create a simple timer.  A button is pressed to start the stopwatch until the button is pressed again.  The running time is displayed until the stop button is pressed.  It only needs to be accurate to a hundredth of a second.  My question is if the System.Diagnostics::Stopwatch class is the best choice for this application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the `Stopwatch` class is intended for very precise (microseconds or better) measurements, not for accuracy (it may not be synchronized with wall time).

The best way to implement this is to start a regular UI timer and record the start time (perhaps `DateTime.UtcNow`). Whenever the timer ticks just update the display with the current time minus the start time.